# Oracle PLSQL Error while executing an anonymous block - Encountered the symbol "LOOP"

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have written a small anonymous code block in PLSQL using For Loop. But it faield to execute with the error. I am using SQL Developer to execute it.

Code Block:

```
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN ('SELECT 1 from dual')
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sysdate);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Error:

```
Error starting at line 2 in command:
DECLARE
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN ('SELECT 1 from dual')
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sysdate);
  END LOOP;
END;
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP" when expecting one of the following:

   * & - + / at mod remainder rem .. <an exponent (**)> ||
   multiset year day
ORA-06550: line 6, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
   exists prior
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: Remove the single quotes around the select statement

Comment: Ahh! Thank You 'a_horse_with_no_name'.